# Use HTML template e-mail body in Google Gmail API on C#

Tags: c#, html, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm currently developing an app in .NET c# for my own company and I'm facing some trouble when trying to use a HTML template to send a automated e-mail to my users with my app in c#.

**C# Code to send e-mail using Gmail API**

```
public bool sendEmail(SendEmailModel email)
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential credential = loadCredentials();
            string message = $"To: {email.receiver}\r\nSubject: {email.subject}\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>{email.content}</h1>";
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = ApplicationName });
            var msg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
            
            msg.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(message.ToString());
            service.Users.Messages.Send(msg, "me").Execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "");
    }
```

**HTML Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <title></title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    
    <style>

        html,
body {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

* {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

table,
td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

*[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
.unstyle-auto-detected-links *,
.aBn {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    cursor: default !important;
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

.a6S {
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 0.01 !important;
}

.im {
    color: inherit !important;
}

img.g-img + div {
    display: none !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {
    u ~ div .email-container {
        min-width: 320px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {
    u ~ div .email-container {
        min-width: 375px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) {
    u ~ div .email-container {
        min-width: 414px !important;
    }
}


    </style>

    <style>

        .primary{
    background: #17bebb;
}
.bg_white{
    background: #ffffff;
}
.bg_light{
    background: #f7fafa;
}
.bg_black{
    background: #000000;
}
.bg_dark{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
.email-section{
    padding:2.5em;
}

.btn{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn.btn-primary{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #e77d1a;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.btn.btn-white{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
.btn.btn-white-outline{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #e77d1a;
    color: #e77d1a;
}
.btn.btn-black-outline{
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.btn-custom{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

a{
    color: #17bebb;
}

table{
}

.logo h1{
    margin: 0;
}
.logo h1 a{
    color: #17bebb;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.hero{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.hero .text{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.hero .text h2{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.hero .text h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.hero .text h2 span{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #000;
}

.text-author{
    bordeR: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em;
}
.text-author img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.text-author h3{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul.social{
    padding: 0;
}
ul.social li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.footer{
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.footer .heading{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.footer ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.footer ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.footer ul li a{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {


}
    </style>


</head>
    <center style="width: 100%; background-color: #f1f1f1;">
    <div style=" display: none; font-size: 1px;max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;"></div>
    <div style=" max-width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
      <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #dedede; margin: auto;">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" class="hero bg_white" style="background-color: #dedede; padding: 2em 0 2em 0;">
            <div class="text-author" style="border-radius: 20px;background-color: #ffffff;border-color: #ffffff; ">
                <table table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <img src="{LOGO_1}" style="height: 100px; width: auto;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <h3 class="name" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 25px; color: #171717;">Olá,</h3>
                            <span class="position">{content}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <p><a class="btn btn-white-outline" style="width: 94%;">{btn_1_content}</a></p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 94%;">{btn_2_content}</a></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                            <span class="position" style="color: #dbdbdb;">Este é um e-mail enviado automaticamente.</span>
                            <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <div class="separator" style="background-color: #d7d7d7; height: 1px;"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">
                            <div style="height: 20px;"></div>
                            <span class="position" style="color: #dbdbdb;">Se você já realizou o pagamento desse boleto desconsidere esse e-mail.</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <h3 class="name" style="font-weight: 250; font-size: 16px; color: #171717;">Abraços,</h3>
                            <h3 class="name" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 16px; color: #171717;">Equipe Acalanto.</h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div>
                    <img src="{LOGO_2}" height="60px">
                    <h3 style="color: #898989; font-size: 14px;">© Organização Diamante LTDA</h3>
                </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea on how to use any kind of template with Gmail API. If Gmail API isn't the "go" for this case please let me know, I don't mind to use othe types of e-mail services but I really like Google stuff, but, in this case they don't have any info on .NET c# or even on how to use templates.

Comment: Out of curiosity can i see the code you are using to authorize this?    loadCredentials();  <-- that

Comment: Sure, the code is: `using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pathToCredential + "/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                        path = Path.Combine(path, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");
                        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(path, true)).Result;
                    }`

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync  <--- thats for installed apps you wont be able to host this on a website you know.   The authorization consent screen will be opened on the machine the code is running on so it will try to open on the webserver.

Comment: But that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Okay just make sure you are aware that this code wont run on a web server.  I miss understood and thought you were going to host this for users.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I'm not using it for the general public, only for my own company.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

After some thought I found the solution.

In the line of code:

```
tring message = $"To: {email.receiver}\r\nSubject: {email.subject}\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>{email.content}</h1>";
```

I just replaced `<h1>{email.content}</h1>` with `File.ReadAllText("PATH_TO_HTML_FILE")` and that was it. Sorry for the dumb question. In my opinion, Google should update their Gmail API documentation and examples, because I don't think anyone will go to the trouble of implementing a e-mail api and e-mail system to send simple e-mails with plain text and images.